# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null

Tags: javascript, null

I get this error in a ajax response:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/search",
        data: {
            s: value,
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('data is:', data);
            if (data != null) { 
                    jsonObject = JSON.parse(data);
                    jsonObject.forEach(function (data) { //error here
               // do stuff
            } else {
                console.log('null data received');
            }
```

But I always get this error:

```
data is: null
projects.js:23 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of null
    at Object.success (projects.js:23)
    at c (jquery-3.5.1.min.js?1624781025:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-3.5.1.min.js?1624781025:2)
    at l (jquery-3.5.1.min.js?1624781025:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.5.1.min.js?1624781025:2)
```

What is wrong with my conditional to find null data, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says that `jsonObject` is `null`.

You are testing if `data` is `null`.

Therefore `data` must `null` expressed as JSON so `data` is the **string** `null`.

(`"null" != null`)

Comment: I see. I supposed when data is not null, it can be parsed because server sends json object or null. So how can I fix this?

Comment: You can test is the result of parsing the JSON is null.